# How to redirect to 404 several URLs

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I have correct 404 error configuration on my website in overall. However I would like to redirect several non-standard URLs to 404 page

Can you advice how can I achieve this ? best with .htaccess

Thanks

Comment: Example URL to redirect would have following format


website.com/url1.html
website.com/url2.html

Comment: so you want all .html urls to 404 ?

Comment: ok i found the way Redirect 404 /url.html

Answer (score 0):

To redirect all urls with .html

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.html
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

To redirect a specific url you can use

```
Redirect 404 /url1.html
Redirect 404 /url2.html
```

Answer (score 0):

To redirect all non existent requests to 404 page you can use the following Code

```
ErrorDocument 404 /your404page.html
```